# Random value json in php

Tags: php, json

I want PHP to echo random one result in Json Link: http://havanzee.tk/api/quote.json

Data in the link is:-

```
{ "danh-ngon": [
   {
      "content": "Hãy bắt đầu làm những việc cần thiết, sau đó làm những việc bạn có thể, và tự nhiên bạn có thể làm những điều không thể"
   },
   {
      "content": "Điều tuyệt vời nhất trên thế giới bạn không thể nhìn thấy và chạm được- bạn sẽ phải cảm nhận chúng bằng trái tim."
   },
   {
      "content": "Tôi không thể thay đổi hướng gió, nhưng tôi có thể thay đổi con đường tôi đi để đạt được đến nơi mà tôi muốn"
   },
   {
      "content": "Bạn phải làm những điều mà bạn nghĩ rằng mình không thể "
   },
   {
      "content": "Sự hoàn hảo dường như không thể đạt được, nhưng nếu chúng ta theo đuổi sự hoàn hảo thì chúng ta sẽ chạm đến sự \nxuất sắc."
   },
   {
      "content": "Không có gì là không thể, chính từ này cũng nói lên rằng tôi có thể"
   },
   {
      "content": "Cơ hội luôn chào đón chúng ta, hãy nắm lấy nó"
   },
   {
      "content": "Chún ta biết chúng là là ai, nhưng chúng ta không biết những điều chúng ta có thể làm được"
   },
   {
      "content": "Một người sáng tạo luôn bị thôi thúc bởi khát vọng của sự thành công, chứ không phải khát vọng đánh bại người khác"
   },
   {
      "content": "Luôn cố gắng hết sức thực hiện kế hoạch của bạn, bạn sẽ gặp hái thành công sau này"
   },
   {
      "content": "Những gì bạn làm hôm nay có thể cải thiện tương lai"
   },
   {
      "content": "Thất bại không bao giờ xảy ra nếu quyết tâm thành công của chúng ta đủ mạnh"
   },
   {
      "content": "Luôn cố gắng hết sức thực hiện kế hoạch của bạn, bạn sẽ gặp hái thành công sau này."
   },
   {
      "content": "Ngày mới bắt đầu với suy nghĩ mới và sức mạnh mới"
   },
   {
      "content": "Đừng nhìn lại xem bạn đã làm những gì. Hãy cứ tiếp tục đi"
   },
   {
      "content": "Một người sáng tạo luôn bị thôi thúc bởi khát vọng của sự thành công, chứ không phải khát vọng đánh bại người khác"
   },
   {
      "content": "Cuộc sống không phải là một vấn đề cần giải quyết, mà là thực tế để chúng ta cần trải nghiệm"
   },
   {
      "content": "Điều quan trọng nhất để tận hưởng cuộc sống của chúng ta là hãy luôn hạnh phúc."
   },
   {
      "content": "Cuộc sống không phải là đi tìm con người thật của bạn. Cuộc sống tạo ra bản thân bạn"
   },
   {
      "content": "Cuộc sống này thực sự đơn giản, nhưng chúng ta luôn làm nó trở nên phức tạp"
   },
   {
      "content": "Chúng ta không thể nhớ những ngày đã qua, nhưng chúng ta có thể nhớ những khoảnh khắc"
   },
   {
      "content": "Cuộc sống hạnh phúc thật đơn giản, tất cả điều phụ thuộc vào bạn, tùy thuộc vào cách bạn suy nghĩ"
   },
   {
      "content": "Cuộc sống được đánh giá không phải bằng số năm bạn sống mà là cách bạn sống trong những năm đó"
   },
   {
      "content": "Cuộc sống là những thông điệp"
   },
   {
      "content": "Hãy quay về hướng mặt trời, và bạn sẽ không thấy bóng tối"
   },
   {
      " content": "Hãy tìm đến nơi có niềm vui, bởi niềm vui có thể xóa đi những đau khổ "
   },
   {
      "content": "Có một điều mà chúng ta có thể làm được tốt hơn bất kì ai khác: chúng ta có thể là chính mình"
   },
   {
      "content": "Ngày hôm qua chúng ta không thể lấy lại, nhưng ngày hôm nay là ngày chúng ta có thể chiến thắng hoặc thất bại "
   },
   {
      "content": "Bạn không tìm kiếm tình yêu, mà là tình yêu tìm đến bạn"
   },
   {
      "content": "Khi gặp nhau hãy bắt đầu bằng một nụ cười, bởi nụ cười là sự khỏi đầu của tình yêu"
   }
]}
```

PHP echo random content

Thanks

Comment: I want it's not a question....show what you have tried first and read this [mcve]

Comment: use `file_get_contents()` to get data from link and then do `json_decode()`  and use `rand()` to get randome index and `echo` content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://havanzee.tk/api/quote.json');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    $strc = json_decode(curl_exec($curl),true);
    curl_close($curl);
     $i = rand(0,count($strc['danh-ngon'])-1);
    echo $strc['danh-ngon'][$i]['content'];
```

Comment: `file_get_contents()` will be better idea

Comment: @AlivetoDie define *better* please

Comment: `$i = rand(0,count($strc['danh-ngon']));` will at some point throw Notice: Undefined offset as count returns the number of items in the array, whereas the max index of the array is count -1, it should thus be: `$i = rand(0,count($strc['danh-ngon'])-1);`

Comment: @lovelace thank you for pointing out, i updated my answer